# Can't find `mapproxy-util` after MapProxy installation

Tags: python, mapproxy

I'm trying to install MapProxy on a Windows machine. My hope is that I can install it and test it on my own computer before moving it to a server. At the moment I can't seem to find `mapproxy-util` and to be honest I don't understand how I am supposed to call it. I have read the [tutorial at mapproxy.org](https://mapproxy.org/docs/nightly/tutorial.html) but if anyone knows of some other online tutorials that have been helpful I would really like to hear about it. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: mapproxy-util --version to check mapproxy is installed

Comment: I can import MapProxy into a python script, I can also import version and get it to return the version of MapProxy I have installed but I can't find mapproxy-util

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the problem was that I had not set the path to the folder where mapproxy was installed, beginners' mistake. I installed mapproxy using `easy_install` so everything was put in to the `python26/Scripts` folder.